# How can I distinguish lists from strings in django templates

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I'm developing a project on Google AppEngine, using Django templates, so I have to use tags like `{{ aitem.Author }}` to print content within my HTML template.

`Author`, however, can either be a *string* or a *list* object, and I have no way to tell it in advance. When the Author is a list and I try to print it on my template, I get the ugly result of

> Author: **[u'J. K. Rowling', u'Mary GrandPr\xe9']**

Is there any way to handle this kind of scenario (basically printing a field differently depending on its type) effectively? Do I have to rely on custom tags or any other means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution would be to add a method to the model `get_authors()` which always returns a list either of one or more authors. Then you can use:

```
Author: {{ aitem.get_authors|join:", " }}
```

If you for some reason have only access to the templates and can't change the model, then you can use a hack like this:

```
{% if "[" == aitem.Author|pprint|slice:":1" %}
    Author: {{ aitem.Author|join:", " }}
{% else %}
    Author: {{ aitem.Author }}
{% endif %}
```

P.S. it's not a good convention to use capital letters for attribute names.

Comment: You're right, but unfortunately I'm not able to modify the model for that: I'm using a library and can't easily change that thing. That explains the ill-named properties, too.

Comment: Instead of `pprint`, isn't better to check for a type specific method? E.g. `if author.islower` only evaluates true if string.

Comment: Nice idea. I haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Aidas's `get_authors()` solution is the best, but an alternative might be to create a template tag that does the test. You'll want to read up on [custom template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), but they aren't that hard to create if you look at the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Matthew's advice and eventually implemented a filter to handle lists.
I'm posting it here just in case someone else needs it.

```
@register.filter(name='fixlist')
def fixlist(author):
    if type(author) == list:
        return ', '.join(author)
    else:
        return author
```

I call it from the template pages like this `{{ aitem.Author|fixlist }}`

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It's probably hipper to say `if isinstance(author, list):`